# Simple PHP issue that I cant seem to get to work

Tags: php

Im working on a simple roll a dice program. So it has to generate a random number from 0-5 and when it selects 0-4 it echo's and when it selects 5 it echo's.

To it keeps echo the first echo 'you got 6'. I cant seem to get my mind around this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A loop of your own</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$trows = 0;
$dice = 0;

while ($dice == 0)
{
$dice = rand(0,5);
$trows++;
}

if ($dice = 5)
{
    echo 'you got 6';
}

else 
{
    echo 'you got 1-5';
}

echo '<br><br>';
echo $trows;

?>

</body>
```

Comment: `if ($dice = 5)` should be `if ($dice == 5)`. You're doing an assignment instead of a comparison.

Comment: This code confuses me, why the while loop? And why not rand(1,6) ?

Comment: Thank you that seems to work ! You have been a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($dice = 5)
```

Is actually assigning the value of 5 to dice, rather than comparing the values, so the first part of the if statement will be entered, rather than the else.

```
if ($dice == 5)
```

is what you are looking for

*Edit*: From your comments I think this is what you are looking for

```
$trows = 0;
$dice = 0;

while ($dice != 5)
{
    $dice = rand(0,5);
    $trows++;

    if ($dice == 5) {
        echo 'you got 6';
    } else {
        echo 'you got 1-5';
    }

    echo '<br><br>';
    echo $trows;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, however when I echo $trows it always shows 1. It seems the $trows++ is not working correctly anymore.

Comment: Are you expecting the dice to be rolled a given number of times? What you are actually doing is saying, while the dice roll is 0, roll again, until it is no longer 0.

Comment: I wanted it to count the trows howmany it takes until it randomly picks 5

Comment: So maybe you want while($dice != 5) and move the if ($dice == 5) logic into the while, so you get an echo for each roll

Comment: I've edited my answer, so that it's closer to what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for your effords, This wil do the trick !

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement is not testing for a condition, but rather performing an assignment and then evaluating the truth of that assignment (which will always be true in this case).

Your code should be:

```
if($dice == 5)
{
    echo 'you got 1-5';
}
```

Notice the `==` instead of the single `=`

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
while ($trows == 0)
{
   $dice = rand(0,5);
   if ($dice == 5)
   {
     echo 'you got 6';
   }

   else 
   {
     echo 'you got 1-5';
     $trows++;
   }

}
```